# How to make date picker shorter?

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages, vs-web-application-project

So my date picker is very long. It shouldn't be that long, but i dont know how to shorten it.
This is the codes I used to get the date picker.

```
[BindProperty, DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }


    <br />public void OnPostTestClick()
        {
            String testparam = Request.Form["navn"];
            String testDate = Request.Form["Date"];
            Debug.WriteLine("Testclick verdi = " + testparam);
            Debug.WriteLine("Testclick verdi2 = " + testDate);
            filterdato = testDate;
            ListData();
        }
```

from a cshtml.cs file

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="TestClick">
    <input name="name" id="name" />
    <button>seacrh</button>

    <br />
    <br />
    <input class="form-control" type="date" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Date field is required." id="Date" name="Date" value="åååå-mm-dd" />
    <br />
</form>
```

from a cshtml file.

This is a picture of what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVcyZ.jpg

As you see, it has a lot spaces after the text. I was wondering how I can fix this.

Comment: Have you checked the css of the datepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form-control` class that you are using is a [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) class. One of the styles that `form-control` class adds is `width: 100%;`. Check Bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/layout/) for how to create form layouts.

Or remove `form-control` class from your `input` element.